# Twenty Twelve Author not displaying

Tags: theme-development, author, theme-customizer

I have a WordPress blog. On which I want to display author name with each post.
I have tried various plugins but these don't work for me. This is the address of blog: http://altuslift.com/blog/

I want to show the name of author with date.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Go into your themes single.php file and put this code in a proper place under the the_title();

```
This Post was written by <?php the_author(); ?>
```